# Retrieve data from phpmyadmin

Tags: php

I wrote this code to retrieve data from phpmyadmin. But when the i load the page "retrieve.php" in my browser then all the result show up without any search. Later when i do search by specific name then those field go and only the one that i searched for show. May i know how do i get rid of the display that i get when i am not doing any search ? Basically what i want to do is that when i load the page "retrieve.php" then no field from database should display until i search for any specific name.

```html
<?php
 echo "<body style='background-color:gray'>";
include ("account.php");
( $dbh = mysql_connect( $hostname, $username, $password ))
 or die ( "uable to connect to MYSQL database" );
mysql_select_db( $project );


$sql= "SELECT * FROM registration ";


$query=mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

if (isset($_POST['search'])) {
 
 $search_term = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['search_box']);
 
 $sql .= "WHERE first_name= '{$search_term}'";
 
 $sql .= " OR last_name= '{$search_term}'";

}


$query=mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

?>



<html>  
<head>  
<title>jon</title>  
</head>  
<body>  
<form name="search_form" method="POST" action="retrieve.php">  
<table width="599" border="1">  
<tr>  
<th>Search

<input type ="text" name ="search_box" value=""/>
<input type="submit" name="search" value="Find Users">
  
</tr>  
</table>  
</form>  


<table width="600" border="1">  
<tr>  
<th width="91"> <div align="center">First Name </div></th>  
<th width="98"> <div align="center">Last Name </div></th>  
<th width="198"> <div align="center">Email </div></th>  
<th width="97"> <div align="center">City </div></th>  
<th width="59"> <div align="center">Country </div></th>   
 
<tr>


<?php  while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($query)){ ?>


<tr>
 <td><?php echo $row['first_name'];?></td>
 <td><?php echo $row['last_name'];?></td>
 <td><?php echo $row['email'];?></td>
 <td><?php echo $row['address_city'];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['address_country'];?></td>
 
 
 
<tr>
 
<?php } ?>

</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
<?php
 echo "<body style='background-color:gray'>";
include ("account.php");
( $dbh = mysql_connect( $hostname, $username, $password ))
    or die ( "uable to connect to MYSQL database" );
mysql_select_db( $project );


if (isset($_POST['search'])) {
    $sql= "SELECT * FROM registration ";

    $search_term = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['search_box']);

    $sql .= "WHERE first_name= '{$search_term}'";

    $sql .= " OR last_name= '{$search_term}'";
    $query=mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
}



?>



<html>  
<head>  
<title>jon</title>  
</head>  
<body>  
<form name="search_form" method="POST" action="retrieve.php">  
<table width="599" border="1">  
<tr>  
<th>Search

<input type ="text" name ="search_box" value=""/>
<input type="submit" name="search" value="Find Users">

</tr>  
</table>  
</form>  


<table width="600" border="1">  
<tr>  
<th width="91"> <div align="center">First Name </div></th>  
<th width="98"> <div align="center">Last Name </div></th>  
<th width="198"> <div align="center">Email </div></th>  
<th width="97"> <div align="center">City </div></th>  
<th width="59"> <div align="center">Country </div></th>     

<tr>


<?php  if (isset($_POST['search'])) {
while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($query)){ ?>


<tr>
    <td><?php echo $row['first_name'];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['last_name'];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['email'];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['address_city'];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['address_country'];?></td>



<tr>

<?php }} ?>

</table>
```

Only do the query if there is a post result. Make sure to swap to MySQLi_* when you have the time as MySQL_* is depreciated.

Comment: As you can see i am new to this. Thank you for explaining this to me.